# How to display only selected invisible files on mac osx 10.+?

Tags: mac, macos, finder

I have a question. Is that possible or not i really don't know.

I use Yosemite. And i ran this command via terminal.app

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;killall Finder
```

this command show all hidden files on my mac. but i just want to make visible only, .htaccess files . Is that possible ? Or not ? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either show all hidden files or none, there is no in-between.

The only way that I know of to easily access dot-files is to create a link to a visible file. For example, you could create a link from ".htaccess" to "htaccess.txt" and then "htaccess.txt" would be visible

Here's a way to make those link for all of the .htaccess files in the current directory and all subdirectories in Terminal:

```
find . -type f -iname .htaccess -execdir ln -s {} htaccess.txt \;
```

Comment: You may also want to alter the contents of your .htaccess files to prohibit the download of the new htaccess.txt file.